# Cleaning up Visual Studio 2010 download questions

Tags: discussion, clean-up, broken-link

Background: In February 2017, all Visual Studio 2010 ISO image download links stopped working. As a result, at least a few questions requesting download links to the ISO images were soon deleted.

However, there are some questions still remaining asking (approximately) the same thing. These are all I've found:

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953588/visual-studio-2010-express-with-sp1-integrated</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119698/visual-c-sharp-2010-express-full-download</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078854/where-can-i-download-full-autonomous-offline-installer-of-visual-studio-2010-sp</s> (deleted)
- <s>[is there SP1 for visual-studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109976/is-there-sp1-for-visual-studio-2010)</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465800/where-to-download-visual-studio-full-version</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301550/where-to-download-visual-studio-2010-for-use-with-my-product-key</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421884/is-it-possible-to-download-standalone-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1</s> (deleted)

The last one of those actually has a [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43583974/1128737) that says the ISO image is available to MSDN subscribers.

What should be done with those questions? My suggestion would be to:

- Delete all above questions except the last one and redirect them to the last one if possible.
- For the last question, close it and delete all answers except the most recent one.

Most answerers and questioners (those who have score >= 3) [wouldn't lose](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/06/reputation-and-historical-archives/) their reputation as the result of the deletions.

There are also some very related questions asking something about VS 2010 downloads, most of which should probably be handled somehow:

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115752/vs2010-sp1-files-available-with-web-installer</s> (deleted)
- [Visual Studio 2010 choose version to Download? (x86/x64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645735/visual-studio-2010-download) (does not ask for download link but about x86/x64 versions -> improve title and leave open? - **done**)
- <s>[Visual studio 2010 community edition free download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394316/visual-studio-2010-community-edition-free-download)</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599153/is-visual-studio-2010-still-available-for-download</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406046/visual-studio-2010-hotfixes</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891737/downloading-visual-studio-2010-beta</s> (deleted)

Comment: Shouldn't almost all off this questions be off-topic because they ask for a off-site resource?

Comment: Yeah all resource requests are off topic; this question is asking how to handle them best in this case (for example, a mere closure is unlikely to be the best option because the links will probably remain dead).

Comment: Close as dupes of the one with the MSDN subscriber answer?

Comment: Hmm, glad somebody posted about this. It is quite a mess. The worst part is, most of the highly upvoted answers are useless. I agree with SMI that close / delete isn't the best option, it's hard enough to find straight answers on older VS versions with Microsoft redesigning their site every 15 seconds. A FAQ style, community wiki SO post could help with this. [Remember that running VS 2010 without SP1 will not only cause cryptic errors on VS 2010, but every newer version of VS on that computer...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10888391/4975230)

Comment: Also these "help me find an offline installer download page" Qs for [VS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24582492/4975230) and [VS 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070584/how-to-install-vs2015-community-edition-offline/30077959) could use some cleanup too. Useful questions (IMO) but hard to keep up to date; again I think some kind of CW post would probably be the best solution

Comment: I guess since it looks like SO is going with the "close and delete" route (which I disagree with myself, but oh well, I tried), it would be nice to have some kind of blog post that presents a sane guide for how to find all of this stuff... any takers? Judging from the views those posts got, it would probably be worth somebody's time to host that. I'd do it but I don't have a personal site.

Comment: @jrh seems to me that information belongs on MSDN, not some random blog. Document at the source.

Comment: @Gimby In a perfect world you're right, but in reality Microsoft helped create this mess. Microsoft seems to want to do everything they can think of to make offline installers and older versions of Visual Studio disappear, despite quite a lot of people wanting them (based on views of those questions). For example the project I'm on is trying to upgrade some old systems, but for right now I need to keep using an old version of VS to keep the code in sync because the older systems can't run VS <Insert newest version here that changes every 2 years>.

Comment: Also one bit of useful information that should probably be preserved [from Wyatt8740 regarding command line parameters for offline installers:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119698/visual-c-sharp-2010-express-full-download#comment49122624_8119734) @MarekGrzenkowicz alright, just got an offline VC# 2010 link by sniffing URL's while the downloader was running. http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/D/3/BD3C8C9F-621B-4155-8D07-68DC94D34306/EXPRESS/ixpvcs.exe Extract with 7-zip, run the .MSI inside with msiexec /i vs_setup.msi NOVSUI=1.

Answer (score 1):

Questions asking which tool/off-site resource to use or where to find it are off-topic and should get closed as such.

Questions about how to install programming tools are borderline between SO and https://superuser.com. As a rule of thub:

- if the installation question requires programming domain knowledge, in this case knowledge about C++, libraries, the Visual Studio IDE or RAD functionality etc, then it is on-topic.
- if the installation question is regarding non-programming topics, such as Windows or PC issues during installation of a generic piece of software, it should be closed as off-topic.

If you have gathered a collection of bad questions that should get closed, I would recommend you to join the [SO Close Vote Review chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and directly ask for help from other users to close these questions.

Comment: You're right in that these posts are a near perfect demonstration as to why SO is a poor site for collecting external links, though [there are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) [some famous exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents); how did those posts get started originally? I don't see a "historical lock" message on those posts?

Comment: @jrh Mostly they got started before SO on-topic policies had settled down. "Historical lock" mostly means that "this question is bad and should get deleted, but SO is too greedy to give up the traffic it gets from it".