# Cleaning up and closing "Where to download" questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, clean-up

I just realized that there are lots of "Where to download" questions around which are seeking for off-site ressources and which are still open (there already was a similar call for [VS2010 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348615/cleaning-up-visual-studio-2010-download-questions)). Also, a lot of questions contain outdated links.

I think these questions should be (at least) closed or even deleted (maybe as a second step).

As of 2017-08-31 08:06 UTC there are 576 open questions and 76 already closed ones.

- Still open questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Where+to+download%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano
- Already closed questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Where+to+download%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes

Related:

- "where can I get": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Where+can+I+get%22+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano

Comment: Let's bring this back!